# Python Serial() not etablishing on start up

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron, pyserial

I've made a python script to read information from Serial port. I want this script to run at the boot of my ubuntu. 
I've made my python file executable, and added a lign to the crontab : `@reboot sleep 10s; python /home/MyUser/Documents/MyScript.py &`

The script is indeed started when i'm booting but it's seems like the specific line `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)` won't work. Indeed, if I try to execute something before, it will work, but not after.

I can't figure out why it's not working. When i'm executing my script from the terminal, it does work without problem.

I believe it may be because of the fact that the serial port may not be ready yet when the script start but even when adding a longer sleep before the script start, it doesn't work. I'm running out of ideas and I really need your help.

Here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import serial
import subprocess
import os
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
os.system('export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force off &') #this line won't work, that's why I know the problem is coming from the serial beginning. 
time.sleep(60)
urgency = 0
diffusion = 0
while 1 :
   line = ser.readline().strip()
   if line == "start":
    #do something


   else
    #do something else
```

Comment: try with sudo python !!!

Comment: @legend-is-back Not working unfortunetly

Comment: try putting time.sleep(a minute for example) in program before import serial and the rest of the program and see what happens !!!

Comment: @legend-is-back This indeed worked ! Apparently, the emitter wasn't ready yet when the python tried to etablish the communication ! Thank you !